# How is she to describe how she likes him, when he doesn't know?

Tags: phrase-requests, literature

There's a friend of mine—let's call her Lily—and a guy—David. Lily told me that she feels very happy each time she meets, talks, plays games, dines (and so on) with David. I guess she's falling in love. But she is very perplexed these days, because she likes him, but can't be sure—wants to but is afraid to make sure—whether David likes her or not. So she has decided to write something about that emotion, rather than telling David directly (thus prompting him to say "yes, I like you too").

Here is my question—for what perplexes her has also perplexed me:

**In what Literary and Artistic way can she describe that emotion?**

Comment: In this case, Lily is not sure if the feelings of interest are mutual. Lily should tell David that she was hoping to improve her English by practicing conversing with him. If David accepts, then it is Lily's chance to seduce him.

Comment: Try "I like you. If you like me, please check this box []" then send it via schoolground courier. It worked for me in seventh grade. Good luck. I've got my fingers crossed for Lily.

Comment: I suggest you would probably get better answers at [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/). Failing that, I suggest that you buy her a copy of *Cyrano de Bergerac*, by the French playwright Edmond Rostand. It may offer her many highly literary ideas; and even if it doesn't it is a very romantic and moving play which will provide her a very good cry. And then she can inscribe the book with an affectionate note and give it to David. — By the way, did you know that *Teifi* is the Welsh spelling of *Davey*?

Comment: @StoneyB: I agree. I have voted to migrate (Off Topic => Writers).

Comment: @KitFox she's very shine and graduated. Your comment reminds me of the past. Thanks :)

Comment: @StoneyB sorry, I don't know Writers before. I initially thought _Teifi_ is an old written of _Toffees_, but finally found out it's a river.

Comment: Lots of ideas in Shakespeare...

Comment: @JAM, yeah, but she'd have to persuade him she's a boy. And anyway, Shakespeare's heroines mostly fall in love with horrible men.

Comment: @StoneyB but the sonnets...

Comment: @JAM ... only works if she really *is* a boy. I find Shakespeare's sonnets pretty bland. Wyatt, on the other hand ...

Comment: I don't think that Writers will take this, since it is more like a request to write something, but I will ask if it might be migrated there.  You might come to [The Overlook Hotel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) which is the Writers chat room when you have enough rep to talk. You can ask there even if they don't take the question on the site.

Comment: Writers mod here. We don't handle questions about what to write. This is really more of a discussion forum question, and is unanswerable in its current form.